# How to open multiple modal popups with jQuery after action submit in one popup

Tags: jquery

When i submit an action in my parent window it should open a new Poup window and if i submit an action in my popup window it should open second popup. When i submit the second popup the value in the second popup should get reflected in parent window.How to open multiple modal popups with jQuery here? Im implementing this in struts2. Popup is a modal dialog with iframe/AJAX content

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by a "popup"?  that could be either 1) a new window, or 2) a modal dialog with inline content or 3) a modal dialog with iframe/AJAX content.  You need to provide a lot more info.